# Website not responsive despite it seeming so when minimising the window

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a website: https://videogamestore.best that looks fine on desktop. When I'm developing it, I minimise the window and it looks good too. I've added lots of media queries for the margin to keep everything where it should be.

E.g.

```
.products-right-pc:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.products-center-pc {
  margin: -45rem 0 -20rem 35rem; 
  padding-bottom: 2rem; 
  width: 15.8rem; 
  height: 30rem;
}

.products-center-pc .price {
  margin-right: 4.1rem;
}

.products-center-pc:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.products-left-pc {
  margin: 0 0 15rem 7rem; 
  width: 15.8rem;
  height: 30rem;
}
```

I've read somewhere else on SO that manipulating margins this much is not good for responsiveness. Is there any credence to this statement?

I've also added this to my layout header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Shouldn't my site be mobile responsive if I have the meta tag and it looks responsive when minimising the window? Why am I having this issue? What's the simplest solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: For your content to be responsive you may want to try wrapping it into a flexbox or similar responsive div to have the behavior you want. I saw that you already did so with your header.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I'm not very CSS savvy.

Comment: Sure! Let me get to work and I'll give you an update on my lunch break